# How to upload file for SharePoint online using Javasript & RestAPI?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, office365api, rest

Currently, I am trying to create API so that, I will upload a test file to specific folder in SharePoint by using JavaScript with the help of REST API. But hard luck. Please let know any solution and suggestions.

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question so other users can see what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check this [resource](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/91b369/how-to-upload-file-in-document-library-in-sharepoint-using-r/).Using jquery

Comment: Geeting error, String.format ,is not a function.